# Prototype Cell not being used by tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have read many posts about similar problems but nothing seems to work, I am obviously doing something wrong.  I have a TableViewController that is in a StoryBoard (XCode 5).  For the PrototypeCell I set the type to custom and set the Identifier to "pbvcell". I added some labels, changed the background etc..  Here is my tableview delegate method for setting the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"pbvcell"];


// Configure the cell...

PBVlead *lead = [self.leads objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Cell class %@", [cell class]);

UILabel *leadNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
leadNameLabel.text = lead.leadName;
return cell;
}
```

Now the app launches but even after I add an object to the tableview datasource array and do a reload data, the cells are blank, like the custom cell is not being used.  It looks like this should be easy and thats all I need to do.  What on earth am I missing?

Comment: I haven't used Storyboards, but normally you'd need to check if the object returned from `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:]` is `nil`, and if so instantiate a new cell using `[[subclass alloc] initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier:]`.

Comment: @Graham, you don't need to do that if the cell is defined in the storyboard.

Comment: @Graham: Not if the cell is registered as prototype cell in the storyboard. Cells will be instantiated automatically if necessary.

Comment: Try logging leadNameLabel and lead.leadName to make sure neither is nil.

Comment: "What on earth am I missing?" - Debug. Start by adding debug logs to see that you are getting a valid cell, then that you are getting a valid label.

Comment: I can log the cell and I get a UItableViewCell.  ALso,when I Log leadNameLabel I get a UILabel and when I log lead.leadName I gtet the string as expected.

Comment: Also, I added a tag of 100 to the Cell in IB.  WHen I log cell.tag just before returning the cell, I get 100 :-(  I am sure the identifier is set in IB, I have checked that a 100 times.  So...  Nothing is nil, it looks like Cell is in fact my cell BUT my tableview still isnt using this cell.  WHat else???

Comment: Is this controller the only controller in the app?

Comment: Because I embrace my  own stupidity I will tell everyone what was going on here.  I had set the TableCell background to blue and added some UILabels and set there color to white to show up against the blue background.  Run the app, no labels....  What I finally realized is, I had not set the Content View background to blue.  So.....  What was happening was the labels actually are shown in the content view in the view hierarchy.  White labels on a white background equals, invisible... :-)  I set the content view background to blue and wola, there is everything! :-)  Brother...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left this in a comment above but just to keep things tidy I will post it as an answer here.  It is silly but it is good to note that you have to manipulate the contextView of a prototype cell and not the tableview cell itself in order for your visual changes to have an effect...

"Because I embrace my own stupidity I will tell everyone what was going on here. I had set the TableCell background to blue and added some UILabels and set there color to white to show up against the blue background. Run the app, no labels.... What I finally realized is, I had not set the Content View background to blue. So..... What was happening was the labels actually are shown in the content view in the view hierarchy. White labels on a white background equals, invisible... :-) I set the content view background to blue and wola, there is everything! :-) Brother..?